# Failed to initialize the application "DataSource" due to error weblogic.application.ModuleException

Tags: oracle, weblogic, weblogic12c

When I am trying to restart the Application server getting below error. If I manually deploy the datasource.ear file, it is working fine. But it fails during server restart.

```
<Error> <Deployer> <BEA-149205> <Failed to initialize the application "Datasource" due to error weblogic.application.ModuleException: 
weblogic.application.ModuleException: 
    at weblogic.jdbc.module.JDBCModule.prepare(JDBCModule.java:337)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.prepare(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:100)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$1.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:172)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$1.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:167)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:35)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: weblogic.common.ResourceException: weblogic.common.ResourceException: Could not create pool connection. The DBMS driver exception was: IO Error: Connection reset
    at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.ConnectionEnvFactory.createResource(ConnectionEnvFactory.java:288)
    at weblogic.common.resourcepool.ResourcePoolImpl.makeResources(ResourcePoolImpl.java:1310)
    at weblogic.common.resourcepool.ResourcePoolImpl.makeResources(ResourcePoolImpl.java:1227)
    at weblogic.common.resourcepool.ResourcePoolImpl.start(ResourcePoolImpl.java:250)
    at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.ConnectionPool.doStart(ConnectionPool.java:1396)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
```

Comment: <Error> <Deployer> <BEA-149205> <Failed to initialize the application "DataSource" due to error weblogic.application.ModuleException: 
weblogic.application.ModuleException: 
at weblogic.jdbc.module.JDBCModule.prepare(JDBCModule.java:337)
Caused By: weblogic.common.ResourceException: weblogic.common.ResourceException: Could not create pool connection. The DBMS driver exception was: IO Error: Connection reset
 at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.ConnectionEnvFactory.createResource(ConnectionEnvFactory.java:288)

Comment: Check the JDBC Driver version you have in the WLS classpath.
But most likely it seems Database permission issue. Check with your DBA to ensure all permission are there on the DB side.